# coulomb potential

Tags: residue-calculus

How to compute the following integral :

\begin{equation}
I = \int \frac{e^{-q|\mathbf r|}}{|\mathbf r|}e^{i\mathbf k\cdot\mathbf r}. d\mathbf r
\end{equation}

where this 3D volume integral is considered carried out on an unbound domain. This looks like a simple Fourier transform of the Coulomb potential $\frac{e^{-q|\mathbf r|}}{|\mathbf r|}$ .

Integrating in spherical coordinates choosing $\mathbf k$ as the z axis, the integration on $\phi$ provides a factor $2\pi$ leaving the angular integral:

\begin{equation}
I_{\theta} = \int_0^{\pi} e^{ikr\cos\theta}\sin\theta d\theta = \left[ \frac{e^{ikrx}}{ikr}\right]_{-1}^{+1} = \frac{\sin kr}{kr}
\end{equation}

and radial integral :

\begin{equation}
I_r = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-qr}}{r} I_{\theta}(kr)rdr = \Im_m(\int_0^{\infty}  \frac{e^{(ik-q)r}}{kr}dr)
\end{equation}

Using the method of residue could give :

\begin{equation}
I_r = \frac{1}{2k}\Im_m(2i\pi) Res(z\frac{e^{iQz}}{z},0)=\frac{\pi}{k}
\end{equation}
where $Q = k+iq$ is a complex number.

I know the result should eventually give something of the form : 
$I \propto\frac{1}{\mathbf k^2 + q^2}$ 
there must be a mistake in my application of the theorem of residue but can not figure out where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\theta$ integral should give you $I_\theta = \frac{2 \sin(kr)}{kr}$
but more importantly you forgot to cancel the $r$ in the denominator with the $r$ in $r\; dr$.  You should get
 $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{2}{k} \sin(kr) e^{-qr}\; dr = \frac{2}{k^2 + q^2}$$